# Python - Is it recommended to always open file with 'b' mode?

Tags: python-2.7, file-io, binaryfiles

So I have this simple python function:

```
def ReadFile(FilePath):
    with open(FilePath, 'r') as f:
        FileContent = f.readlines()
    return FileContent
```

This function is generic and used to open all sort of files. However when the file opened is a binary file, this function does not perform as expected. Changing the [open()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) call to:

```
with open(FilePath, 'rb') as f:
```

solve the issue for binary files (and seems to keep valid in text files as well)

#### Question:

1. Is it safe and recommended to **always** use `rb` mode for reading a file?
2. If not, what are the cases where it is harmful?
3. If not, How do you know which mode to use if you don't know what type of file you're working with?

---

#### Update

```
FilePath = r'f1.txt'

def ReadFileT(FilePath):
    with open(FilePath, 'r') as f:
        FileContent = f.readlines()
    return FileContent

def ReadFileB(FilePath):
    with open(FilePath, 'rb') as f:
        FileContent = f.readlines()
    return FileContent


with open("Read_r_Write_w", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(ReadFileT(FilePath))

with open("Read_r_Write_wb", 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines(ReadFileT(FilePath))

with open("Read_b_Write_w", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(ReadFileB(FilePath))

with open("Read_b_Write_wb", 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines(ReadFileB(FilePath))
```

where `f1.txt` is:

```
line1

line3
```

Files `Read_b_Write_wb`, `Read_r_Write_wb` & `Read_r_Write_w` eqauls to the source `f1.txt`.

File `Read_b_Write_w` is:

```
line1



line3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Python 2.7 Tutorial:
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

> On Windows, 'b' appended to the mode opens the file in binary mode, so
>   there are also modes like 'rb', 'wb', and 'r+b'. Python on Windows
>   makes a distinction between text and binary files; the end-of-line
>   characters in text files are automatically altered slightly when data
>   is read or written. This behind-the-scenes modification to file data
>   is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll corrupt binary data like that
>   in JPEG or EXE files. Be very careful to use binary mode when reading
>   and writing such files. On Unix, it doesn’t hurt to append a 'b' to
>   the mode, so you can use it platform-independently for all binary
>   files.

My takeaway from that is using 'rb' seems to the best practice, and it looks like you ran into the problem they warn about - opening a binary file with 'r' on Windows.